# Returned random number instead of string value in strings.xml in jsonobject

Tags: android

I have a function that validates field, which return JSONObject

```
private JSONObject validateFields(String field){
    JSONObject returnData = new JSONObject();

    try{
        if (field == "description"){
            if (expensesDescription.length() < 1){
                returnData.put("returnCode",0);
                returnData.put("returnMessage",R.string.expenses_description_validation_length);
            }else{
                returnData.put("returnCode",1);
            }
        }

    }catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(FILE_NAME, "An error has occurred: " + e.toString(), e);
    }

    return returnData;
}
```

as you can see, I put a reference to a string resource for the returnMessage. Just in case, the string resource is:

```
<string name="expenses_description_validation_length">Please enter your expenses\' description.</string>
```

Ok so here's how I called the function

```
private JSONObject dataValidation = new JSONObject();
dataValidation = validateFields("description");
if (Integer.parseInt(dataValidation.getString("returnCode")) == 0){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), dataValidation.getString("returnMessage"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

but the problem is instead of the toast showing the error message, it displays a number "2131427350". What's the problem here?

By the way if I change the returnMessage in the validateFields function to something like

```
returnData.put("returnMessage","some error lalala");
```

the correct "some error lalala" message will be displayed.

Comment: `R.string.expenses_description_validation_length` is an identifier, not a string. use `Context.getString` to get the String value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here

```
returnData.put("returnMessage",R.string.expenses_description_validation_length);
```

you are setting a resources for the  returnMessages key, So your toast should look like

```
 int resId = Integer.parseInt(dataValidation.getString("returnMessage"));
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getString(resId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

this way the resources id, you put in the json is converted back to the localized string

Comment: I tried your answer and it displays an error "Cannot resolve method 'getString(java.lang.String)'. But if I do Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getString(R.string.expenses_description_validation_length), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); it works.